# Pythonic method to read dates in a pandas df to create a list of scores for heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I am trying to figure out a way to generate a 'z score' from a pandas df for use in a calendar heatmap.

[Here is an general example of what I'm trying to emulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz64D.png). It shows day of the week along 'x' axis and weeks along the 'y' axis. Each date has a numerical value 'z score' assigned to it, and creating this z score is where I'm running into trouble.

My df is created from a csv file listing several different tasks with the following columns and some example data:

```
Job,Tool,Start,End
A,Hammer,2020-10-03,2020-11-02
A,Drill,2020-11-05,2020-12-02
A,Hammer,2020-12-03,2020-12-30
```

This data works well for a gantt chart, but it needs to be modified a bit for use with a heatmap. I have been able to use pandas to generate just the dates that matter:

```
def calendarmap():
    d1 = min(dff['Start'])

    d2 = max(dff['End'])

    delta = d2 - d1

    dates_that_matter = [d1 + dt.timedelta(i) for i in range(delta.days+1)]

    etc
```

Regardless of the heatmap method used (sns, go.heatmap, etc), I need to create a list that corresponds to the tool used (z score).

```
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z = z, x = x, y = y)
```

I would like to write a simple script that:

1. Iterates through my dates_that_matter
2. Checks to see if that date is between a Start or End date for every row in my df
3. If the date is present in my df, it should write a z score to a list corresponding to each unique tool. With this example data I would be happy with Hammer = 0.5 and Drill = 1.0.
4. If date is not present, z score assigned should be 0. The date will still be present, but it should reflect that there is no job on that day.
5. Tolerate a different number of tools. In this example there are 3 z score states (0=none, 0.5=hammer, and 1.0=drill) but the number of z score states will likely fluctuate between 2 and 10.

Steps 2 and 5 are the parts that are challenging to me at the moment. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only data creation is answered.
Process flow:

1. From each row of the original data frame, create a data frame with a start date to an end date and add it to the new data frame. (Creation of vertical data)
2. Add a workload column.
3. Aggregate the amount of work by date
4. Add the missing date. (dfs.reindex ())
5. Add columns for the week, day of the week, and month of the month.
   This completes the graph data.
   By the way, for verification, I transformed it into a horizontal format with month and day columns like a calendar.

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    tmp_date = pd.date_range(row['Start'], row['End'], freq='1D')
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(tmp_date), 'Job':row['Job'], 'Tool':row['Tool']})
    dfs = dfs.append(tmp_df, ignore_index=True)
dfs['workload'] = dfs['Tool'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Drill' else 0.5 if x == 'Hammer' else 0.75)
dfs.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
dfs = dfs.groupby(dfs.index)['workload'].sum().to_frame()
dfs = dfs.reindex(pd.date_range(dfs.index.min(), dfs.index.max(), freq='1D',name='Date'), fill_value=0, axis='index')
dfs.reset_index(inplace=True)

import calendar
def getNweek(x):
    first_dayofweek = calendar.monthrange(x.year, x.month)[0]
    offset = (first_dayofweek - 6) % 7
    return (x.day + offset -1) // 7 + 1
dfs['nweek'] = dfs['Date'].apply(lambda x: getNweek(x))
dfs['month'] = dfs['Date'].dt.month
dfs['dayofweek'] = dfs['Date'].dt.dayofweek

dfs.head()
Date    workload    nweek   month   dayofweek
0   2020-10-03  0.5     1   10  5
1   2020-10-04  0.5     2   10  6
2   2020-10-05  0.5     2   10  0
3   2020-10-06  0.5     2   10  1
4   2020-10-07  0.5     2   10  2

dfs = dfs.pivot(index='nweek', columns=['month', 'dayofweek'], values='workload')

import itertools
dow = [6,0,1,2,3,4,5]
m = [10,11,12]
new_cols = list(itertools.product(m,dow))
dfs.reindex(new_cols, axis=1)
    month                    10                 11                              12
dayofweek   6   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   0   1   ...     3   4   5   6   0   1   2   3   4   5
nweek                                                                                   
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     0.50    1.25    1.25    0.0     ...     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     2.0     2.0     0.5     0.5     0.5
2   0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    1.00    1.00    1.0     ...     1.0     1.0     1.0     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5
3   0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    1.00    1.00    1.0     ...     1.0     1.0     1.0     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5
4   0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    1.25    1.25    1.00    1.00    1.0     ...     2.0     2.0     2.0     0.5     0.5     0.5     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
5   1.25    1.25    1.25    1.25    1.25    1.25    1.25    2.00    2.00    NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This was great! I built on this to create dfs for workload color coding and then dfslabel which is used to annotate the heatmap with the dates.